# Fourier phase randomization

Tags: time-series, signal-processing, cross-correlation

Can anybody please explain or point to an online resource that explains the Fourier phase randomization technique? I encountered it in the context of comparing the cross-correlation of two signals before and after Fourier phase randomization. What does it mean when the cross-correlation disappears after Fourier phase randomization? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the original paper that describes the method is the following: [Theiler, J., Eubank, S., Longtin, A., Galdrikian, B., & Doyne Farmer, J. (1992). Testing for nonlinearity in time series: the method of surrogate data. Physica D: Nonlinear Phenomena, 58(1), 77-94.](http://tuvalu.santafe.edu/~jdf/papers/testingnonlinearity.pdf) As the title suggests, it is a test of nonlinearity in time series. As the abstract of the paper explains:

> The method first specifies some linear process as a null hypothesis,
>   then generates surrogate data sets which are consistent with this null
>   hypothesis, and finally computes a discriminating statistic for the
>   original and for each of the surrogate data sets. If the value
>   computed for the original data is significantly different than the
>   ensemble of values computed for the surrogate data, then the null
>   hypothesis is rejected and nonlinearity is detected.

A more detailed explanation from [Podobnik, B., Fu, D. F., Stanley, H. E., & Ivanov, P. C. (2007). Power-law autocorrelated stochastic processes with long-range cross-correlations. The European Physical Journal B, 56(1), 47-52.](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1140/epjb/e2007-00089-3.pdf):

> The procedure creates a surrogate data with the same correlation
>   properties as the original signal. Following the procedure, one
>   performs a Fourier transform on the original time series, preserving
>   the Fourier amplitudes but randomizing the Fourier phases. Finally,
>   one performs an inverse Fourier transform to create surrogate data.

I hope this helps other people who encountered the method in a context where it was not properly explained.

Comment: I think the larger question is why does phase randomization eliminate nonlinear aspects of the data but preserve linear one? This is not explained in the references.